# How to recursively delete multiple files with different extensions?

Tags: linux, bash, find, delete-file

I am trying to write a command to remove recursively several files with different extensions (*.extension1, *.extension2 etc) from the current directory and all its related sub-directories.

So far I got this command from [another post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/377438/how-can-i-recursively-delete-all-files-of-a-specific-extension-in-the-current-di) but I couldn't workout how to adapt it to more than one file in the same command line:

```
find . -name "*.extension1" -type f -delete
```

Is it as simple as below?

```
find . -name "*.extension1";"*.extension2" -type f -delete
```

Just as a **side note**, these are all output files that I do not need, but not all are necessarily always output so some of the extensions might not be present. This is just as a general clean-up command.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
find . \( -name "*.extension1" -o -name "*.extension2" \) -type f -delete
```

find Documents ( -name "*.py" -o -name "*.html" ) -exec file {} \;

OR

```
find . -regextype posix-egrep -regex ".*\.(extension1|extension2)$" -type f -delete
```

Comment: Hello @BroSlow, I am not sure what exactly you are asking me. The first suggestion didn't work. The second one did.

Comment: @Fiztban i think BrowSlow asked me.

Comment: Sorry I just realised some files come out with extensions that are not predictable but before the extension is, example mpd2.xxxxxxxxx where xxx is a randomly generated output. Could you include a way to delete those or is it easier to have it as a second command?

Comment: @Fiztban So you say that extensions should be `extensionsxxx` right? and here `xxx` will any value.

Comment: No no those are fine I have a series of output files that give *.check *.err etc but also some that come out as mpd2.random_ext. The above answer from @konsolebox worked in that regard (though I know not of the pros and cons between the two).

Comment: @Fiztban if i understand correctly then your output files like `*.check *.err` and sometimes you got like `mpd2.xxx_ext` but here `_ext` is fixed and `xxx` have random value. am i right?

Comment: @Jayesh not quite, all of the extension, both the `xxx` and `_ext` are random otherwise it would be a case of using `*.*_ext` I suppose. I hope I have managed to explain it more clearly :D

Comment: @Jayesh I accepted this answer as I had tried the first solution before the edit but the first solution is the most versatile one and I adapted it to both types of file cases and works beautifully. Thank you

Comment: What about case insensitive search? `jpg` or `JPG`?

Answer (score 2):

Just add more options. A regex solution can also apply but this one's better and safer.

```
find . \( -name '*.ext1' -or -name '*.ext2' \) -type f -delete
```

Edit: You probably need `-or` as well. Before deleting, test it first without the `-delete` option. (2) Added a pair of `()` as suggested by gniourf_gniourf.

Comment: Thank you for your response. The first iteration didn't work, trying again post edit.

Comment: Nope unfortunately it isn't working still. I also tried with `"*.ext1"`

Comment: @Fiztban Your `find` probably is not GNU based or is an older version. You can try other suggestions.

Comment: `find . \(-name '*.ext1' -o -name '*.ext2' \) -type f -delete` otherwise `-type f -delete` only applies to `-name '*.ext2'`. Note that `-or` is not POSIX. Use `-o` instead.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf I see. Good suggestion. I actually tried it getting same output but never thought that it actually has a difference. Or should I say I forgot.

Comment: Ah thank you for explaining that (even if not to me-I am new to linux) This option works well!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe regexp will help you

```
find . -regextype posix-awk -regex "(.*.ext1|.*.ext2)" -type f -delete
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution using `rm`:

```sh
rm -rf ./**/*.{txt,nfo,jpg,jpeg,png,exe,url}
```

If you want to delete other files too for e.g. those starting with `sample.` just add that too:

```sh
rm -rf ./**/*.{txt,nfo,jpg,jpeg,png,exe,url} ./**/*/sample.*
```

Answer (score 0):

This simple command will delete all the files with extension1 and extension2 recursively in that directory.
rm `find . -name *.extension1 -o -name *.extentions2`